# Remove Facebook events but keep birthdays from calendar

Tags: calendar, facebook

All these events I haven't responded to / don't want to attend are driving me crazy! I do like having my friend's birthdays in my calendar though. I would like to know if it is possible to remove Facebook events and only show birthdays either on my S Planner or my Google Calendar. I am on a Samsung Galaxy Note II.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to: https://www.facebook.com/events/calendar

[image]

- Click the Gears icon next to **Today** on the top left, then click **Export**

[image]

- Right click **export your friend's birthdays** and select **Copy Link Address**

[image]

- Go to https://www.google.com/calendar/
- Click the arrow next to **Other calendars**
- Select **Add by URL**

[image]

- Paste the URL Address you copied from Facebook in step (3)
- Click **Add calendar**
  [image]

Your Friend's birthdays now show up on your Google Calendar on the web. You can repeat the same process if you wish to add the upcoming events, just select **upcoming events** in step 3.

Wait a bit for the changes to sync to your phone (you should have calendar sync enabled on the same Google account on your phone).

Now on your Android phone/tablet, open the **Calendar** then select **Menu** -> **Settings** -> **{Your Google Account}**. Look for **Friends' Birthdays** and select it.

PRIVACY WARNING: Make sure to leave the **Make the calendar publicly accessible?** checkbox *unselected*.

NOTE: The terminology in step 3 differs between browsers. Chrome shows it as *Copy URL Address*, Firefox shows it as *Copy Link Location*, other browsers may differ a bit, but they all have the same meaning.

NOTE: On your Android Phone I'm assuming you are using the [Google Calendar app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar). S-planner, or other calendar apps may handle this differently.

Answer (score 1):

> All these events I haven't responded to / don't want to attend are
>   driving me crazy!

If you only want to see events you have answered "Attending" or "Maybe attending" then you could try "[Freedom](http://freedom.konscript.com/)", a service that I developed.